# How to get ints/doubles to another page within the same project?

Tags: c#, uwp

So I have another project where I have to let users input a rating between 1 and 9 in two textboxes and have those numbers added to totals and the session tallied when the add menu item is clicked. There is a menu item that sends users to a page where they can see various results (highest amount, total customers, average rating). However, the numbers I can't find a way to transfer the amounts and tallies to the summary page so it can show those results. I can navigate fine between pages but the problem still remains.

note: the problem is less with the program running and just making totAmnt1, totAmnt2, and numCustomers available on the summary page so I can work with them.

I've tried making them strings, i've tried get/set, i've tried using this.frame.navigate(typeof(summarypage), totAmnt1, totAmnt2, numCustomers), that command but a separate one for each, I've tried adding it to the app CS. I even tried to do this.frame.navigate(typeof(summarypage), this.totAmnt1), etc. etc.

```
        public int numCustomers = 0; //tallied sessions
        public double totAmnt1 = 0D; // amount for prune punch
        public double totAmnt2 = 0D; // amount for apple ade
```

```
       private void Summary_Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SummaryPage), totAmnt1);
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SummaryPage), totAmnt2);
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SummaryPage), totAmnt1);
        }
```

expected: can use numCustomers, totAmnt1, and totAmnt2 on summary page.

Results: cannot do that. they are stuck on main page and summary page cannot use them, which summary page needs to use them for.

Answer: I found a method. I'll post here for those having the same issues as I'm having.

```
public class Whatever 
{
    public string whatevs
    {
     get;
     set;
    }
    public string uhgosh
    {
    get;
    set;
    }
}
```

```
        private void Hyplink_hyperlinkbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Whatever s = new Whatever()
            {
                whatevs = text1_textbox.Text,
                uhgosh = text2_textbox.Text
            };
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), s);
        }
```

this will pass textbox data to other textboxs, and whatever is in them including ints. from there, on the new page, you can use those ints/doubles for things. probably a way to make it better but its what I managed to come up with after.... 6 hours? jeez.

Comment: I found you have solved your problem, please post your answer below. avoid post in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I found a method. I'll post here for those having the same issues as I'm having.

```
public class Whatever 
{
    public string whatevs
    {
     get;
     set;
    }
    public string uhgosh
    {
    get;
    set;
    }
}
        private void Hyplink_hyperlinkbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Whatever s = new Whatever()
            {
                whatevs = text1_textbox.Text,
                uhgosh = text2_textbox.Text
            };
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), s);
        }
```

this will pass textbox data to other textboxs, and whatever is in them including ints. from there, on the new page, you can use those ints/doubles for things. probably a way to make it better but its what I managed to come up with after.... 6 hours? jeez.